# Can we use same "Split Based On..." widget for multiple "Send and wait for reply" widget

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I have one  "Split Based On..." widget which has same conditions which i am using for multiple "Send and wait for reply" widget. Please check the attached screenshot.[image]

So my flow is whenever end user sent something system will send default message. If conditions matched it will reply accordingly. Issue is if "No condition matches" then it will trigger "send_and_reply_2" widget. It has same conditions which is in "split_order".

But "split_order" can listen to only one variable and hence it is not working for "send_and_reply_2" widget.

so what should i do to continues looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the "Set Variable" widget, which you can initially set to the response of `send_and_reply_1` and then later to `send_and_reply_2`. This way, the split widget only needs to check on variable (the one you defined).